# Flexible View Component for Slack Record notifications

Tags: apex, slack

I am playing around with the newly released [**Apex SDK for Slack**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/salesforce-slack-sdk/guide/overview.html) and want to built a simple Record Notification feature into my Salesforce app. When a record of specific custom object is inserted it should post a message in a Slack channel.

[image]

As far as I understand [this documentation](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/de/content/learn/projects/collaborate-using-the-salesforce-app-in-slack/set-up-opportunity-alerts-in-slack) it is not yet supported to notify Slack on arbitrary (Custom) record type events.

I am now searching for a low-code (no Schema Field retrival and iteration in View Definition) and flexible (Could be adjusted using [the new Slack Record Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.slack_apps_digital_hq_record_layout_structure.htm&type=5)) solution for displaying arbitrary fields of arbitrary SObjects in a nice Slack View component.

I looked through [the documentation of existing components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/salesforce-slack-sdk/guide/uisf.html) but could not find a [Record Viewer as it exists in Lightning](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-view-form/documentation).

**How would you do it?**

Answer (score 2):

We don't support Slack record layouts in the Apex SDK just yet (hopefully soon) - but URL unfurling will be turned on shortly for "Salesforce for Slack" (the platform app), and those will, by default, use the Slack record layouts to render the data.

Let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: I know my question is cryptic. I wanted something totally different. I was looking for a way to notify in Slack when a Custom Object record is created. Without setting up a complicated View table and Apex which uses schema inspection to find fields. Something like FieldSets, Mini Layouts with nearly no code. Or a Slack View component to display records. As we have it in LWC.

Comment: Have you played with the Salesforce for Slack app and the Flow actions? You can setup notifications that way with zero code and no need to create a custom app.

Comment: No that sounds very interesting. Can you point me to documentation of that feature?

Comment: Here you go: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.notif_builder_custom_slack.htm&type=5

Comment: A great place to start is here higher: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.slack_apps.htm&type=5